Form is being submitted on every keystroke due to the input event listener
I’m developing a word counter web application using HTML, JavaScript, and Flask. The issue I’m encountering is that the form submits on every keystroke, which is not what I want. I need the form to update the word count dynamically without submitting on each keystroke. Below is my current code:
Python Script -
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods =["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    user_input = request.form.get("user_input")
    if user_input:
        print(user_input)
    return render_template("index.html")

""" Step 1 - User types or paste in text
    Step 2 - As soon as someone types in the function
    in python starts """
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

HTML -
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Word Counter</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0;
        }

        textarea, label{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #user_input{
            width: 600px;
            height: 500px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="div1">
            <form id="input_form" action="/" method="POST">
                <label for="user_input">Type or paste your text below </label>
                <textarea name="user_input" id="user_input"></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="div-2">
            <p>Words: <span id="word_count">0</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        const user_inp = document.getElementById("user_input");
        const form_input = document.getElementById("input_form");
        
        user_inp.addEventListener("input", function() {
        form_input.submit();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I don't know how to get past this.

You don't need flask at all, just javascript and event listener will do. Flask or django are used to interact with frontend which will always require redirecting.

I’m used to deploying Flask apps on Vercel, so I thought it would work with this word counter too. However, I guess that’s just more unnecessary steps to reach the same destination. Thanks for helping out!
